Question About Utility Company Antenna Power/Radiation Concerns
Removed due to personal data, thanks

Look up the book, "Human Interaction with Electromagnetic Fields: Computational Models in Dosimetry", by Dragan Poljak and Mario Cvetković. It's thorough, scientific theory and evidence based, factual, and soundly reasoned. That said, there is never anything conclusive in science as we do not know what the future will bring and science must always be evidence-based and therefore ever-tentative to future results. Without a working crystal ball, that book is about all we have in the public arena, for now.

I just purchased a Motorola FRS walkie talkie pair (T600) and in the detailed literature included with it, I am warned about all manner of medical devices from hearing aides to pace makers, as well as warned to use the low-power mode (0.5 W) rather than the higher power (2 W) mode, whenever possible. So even their attorneys are anticipating future results in this area and placing what warnings they can conceive of, just to cover themselves. If you are unconcerned when using a cellphone held to your head or when using handheld radio equipment, then I wouldn't think you have cause for worry.

The strength of a radiated signal falls off according to the square of the distance. At the distance of 500 ft, this is greatly below any concern about human safety.
Aside from 15 W being fairly low power, compare that with a cell phone or walkie-talkie, which might transmit 2 W within 1 cm (~1/30 ft) of your head. The ratio of signal strength would be 15/5002 versus 2/(1/30)2, 1/3,000,000. Yes, the cell-phone or walkie-talkie would have about 3,000,000 times the strength of that utility's signal. And cell-phones and walkie-talkies are considered safe.
Oh -- do you or a neighbor have Wi-Fi? That is continuously transmitting a signal of about the same strength as that cell phone, 24 hours a day!

Question: Since this concept is so alien to me. I did a bit more of an exact measurement of the distance this time around. It's actually 400 feet rather than 500 feet. Would that make a difference in terms of safety or is it still a very far distance? I appreciate the help!

Can you not do the math? Replace 500 with 400.

I was able to do the math, I appreciate the help here!

That's not a lot of power, 2 W is half what a typical two-way portable radio would output. If the radiated power is 15 W that means that the antenna would have gain, roughly
$$ Gain = 10\times log(15~W~/~2~W) = 8.75 dB 
$$
To get this gain the antenna concentrates the power in one direction, instead of that 2 W going out equally in all directions it's focused so the signal in one direction is the same as you would have with a 15 W non-focused signal. With the antenna pointing away from you very little of the power would be coming in your direction. On top of that you have path loss, which attenuates the signal rather quickly, at 500 ft. there's going to be almost no signal reaching you.

I greatly appreciate the insight here. So, I was able to find out more information about the antenna. It's a Yagi antenna which from my research has a directional beam. So, while I am not in the path of the antenna, I am also not completely behind the antenna (close to being behind it but more to the far side of it). The only reason why I ask is because I see that there is a front to back ratio for these types of antenna, which seems to help with determining where you can get "hit" by the antenna for coverage.  I guess my question is,  would almost no signal reaching me?

@VWjetta You’re worrying over nothing. Seriously, go do something better with your time than stressing over an antenna. The stress is worse for you than the RF.

Okay, I appreciate the assistance!
